# BarChart EdgeForm not producing correct colors

Tags: plotting, graphics, style, charts

EdgeForm is not producing correct colors for the borders of my bars. My code:

```
data1 = {{1, 20, 300}, {.1, .2, .2}};
errorbarwidth = -0.1;
thickness = 0.005;
barchart[x_, thick_] := 
Module[{}, 
  errorBar[type_: "Rectangle"][{{x0_, x1_}, {y0_, y1_}}, value_, 
  meta_] := Block[{error}, error = Flatten[meta];
  error = If[error === {}, 0, Last[error]];
  {ChartElementData[type][{{x0, x1}, {y0, y1}}, value, 
  meta], {Black, 
  Line[{{{(x0 + x1)/2, y1 - error}, {(x0 + x1)/2, 
      y1 + error}}, {{1/4 (3 x0 + x1) - x, 
      y1 + error}, {1/4 (x0 + 3 x1) + x, 
      y1 + error}}, {{1/4 (3 x0 + x1) - x, 
      y1 - error}, {1/4 (x0 + 3 x1) + x, y1 - error}}}]}}];
  chartData = MapThread[#1 -> #2 &, data1];
  BarChart[chartData, ChartElementFunction -> errorBar["Rectangle"], 
    AspectRatio -> 0.6, ScalingFunctions -> "Log", 
    AxesStyle -> {Thickness[thick], Thickness[thick]}, 
    ChartStyle -> {Directive[White, EdgeForm[{Thickness[thick], Black}]], 
    Directive[Gray, EdgeForm[{Thickness[thick], Black}]], 
    Directive[Black,EdgeForm[{Thickness[thick], Black}]]}, 
    ChartLabels -> {Text[Style[label1, 14]], Text[Style[label2, 14]], 
    Text[Style[label3, 14]]}, ImageSize -> 700]]

plot1 = barchart[errorbarwidth, thickness]
```

My EdgeForm commands are all specifying the edges to be black, but they come out gray. I am using Mathematica 9 BTW.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out -- turns out the default opacity is not 1 for the borders, making them appear gray. I modified EdgeForm:

```
EdgeForm[{Thickness[thick], Black, Opacity[1]}]
```

and it worked just fine.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution.